# How to only store specific characters of the user's input?

Tags: c++

I want to store the value of specific characters from the user input? like for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
int useryear;
std::cout << "\n\tType your favourite year:\n";
std::cout << "\t >> ";
std::cin.ignore(0);
getline(std::cin, useryear);

return 0;
}
```

So, for example the user entered 1933
How to store only the 19??
or the first two characters they typed?

I think to store the 33 i have to change "cin.ignore(0);" to "cin.ignore(2);"

Comment: can you be more specific in your title and question phrasing about how you want to control what input you receive/retain? your example helps a lot but it would be even better if the question was specific enough not to require the example to understand.

Comment: Why not simply read the input as an integer and then use math to keep the value you want? 1933 divided by 100 is 19, and 1933 modulus 100 is 33.

Comment: You could use one of the [get](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) overloads on the `istream` to limit the number of characters you store in a supplied buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would opt for Remy's suggestion (from the comments) if given the choice.

That being said, you could limit the number of characters you read using one of the `get` overloads of `istream`.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    std::string buffer(3, '\0');
    if (std::cin.get(buffer.data(), 3))
    {
        try
        {
            const int year{std::stoi(buffer)};
            std::cout << "Year: " << year << '\n';
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
        catch(const std::invalid_argument& ex)
        {
            std::cerr << "Invalid input" << '\n';
        } 
    }
}
```